# Store image url in database or compute when necessary for a read heavy application

Tags: database, database-design

I'm uploading images to s3.During every upload I'm storing two versions of the image. One resized compressed version and another original larger version.

Currently, I'm storing the original image's url in a database. The smaller image's url has the same url except the word "compressed" inserted in between.

I have a list() endpoint that returns both the urls (original- retrieved from the database; compressed- computed in the serializer)

This application is extremely read heavy. It's like instagram.

Should I just store the compressed image's url in the database as well or should I compute it?

Answer (score 0):

you can just store  the original size url in database. the other compressed url can be generated from the original one by program.

e.g.
the original url is
`http://xxxx.yyy.zz/picture/123456.jpg`
the compressed url could be
`http://xxxx.yyy.zz/picture/123456_480p.jpg`